# Как сделать "Вы уверены, что хотите закрыть приложение?"

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

**C#, .NET**

Ну, как создать MessageBox и все такое, я знаю. Но как сделать так, чтобы по нажатию "Нет" форма не закрылась? И чтобы это все работало при нажатии на "красный крестик", то есть стандартную кнопку управления окном.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Нужно обрабатывать событие "FormClosing". При нажатии на красный крестик система посылает сообщение, что окно хотят закрыть. Если в обработчике сего события не отменят оное действие, окно закроется, посылая следующее сообщение "FormClosed", где уже ничего отменить нельзя.

Отменяется закрытие примерно так:

```
private void fMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Ну а сообщение с вопросом встроить сюда - пара строк =)

Comment: Понял - пасибо!

Answer (score 6):

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Закрыть?", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No)
        e.Cancel = true;
    else
        e.Cancel = false;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

В VB6 нужно обрабатывать событие Form_Terminate:

```
Private Sub Form_Terminate()
.
.
.
End Sub
```

Comment: Почему Вы упомянули VB6?